# Kaa sandbox building failed with binary demo application

Tags: sandbox, iot, kaa

I try download binary demo application from Kaa sandbox.

Eventually, I am faced with: ‌BUILD FAILED

This is a "**build exception**" from Kaa sandbox:

[image]
Is this problem fixed with the Kaa 1.0.0 Banana Beach ?!

Thanks, Kaa IoT team.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the normal kaa deployment in AWS uses a t12 micro instance. This limits the kaa usage.  Once the limit is crossed this error will occur.

Creating a new instance will solve the problem. I was finding that the same thing was happening for me until I did so.